# CLI (Command Line Interface) Cron Job not getting correct controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface

I have almost successfully setup a Cron job on my server, but I cannot call the correct controller.

When I remove the CLI only if statement I can successfully run the script from my browser.

```
// Make sure the request is being made by a CRON Job
if ( ! $this->input->is_cli_request()) exit('Only CLI access allowed');
```

I am having the output being emailed by the Cron Daemon. I have tried this command and following is my results.

**job :**

```
/usr/bin/php /home/dlp/public_html/abc.org/index.php birthday
```

**Result :**

I get the 2 emails in 1st email HTML output of the default controller `index.php` and  in 2nd email output of `birthdady` controller.

code of my controller is.

```
    <?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Birthday extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('email');  
    }



    /**** function for sending news letter on birthday ****/
    function index()
    {
        error_log("birthday function call",1,"abc@gmail.com");
        exit;

}



}
?>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: are you using $_SERVER somewhere in your CLI script? Can post part of the script, it would be more helpful

Comment: i post the code of controller.

Comment: Maybe you can call using wget (http://whatever_you_used_on_browser) instead of /usr/bin/php call in the cron. The only problem you may have is finding out how to limit caller to cron

Comment: @Aaron Gong its not the issue of limit caller to cron. because on each call i received 2 email in response in 1st email HTML output of the default controller index.php and in 2nd email output of birthdady controller.

Comment: @Haseeb, your code is fine. The problem is most likely your cron settings. Have your cron execute `php-cli` instead of `php`. The STDIN constant used by codeigniters `is_cli_request()` isn't always set while running the standard PHP executable `php`.

Comment: @jeemusu now cron runs fine but in response email i receive this.

Set-Cookie: ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%2204254cee466c2f02a1fc531d33b952c0%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%220.0.0.0%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bb%3A0%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1377596162%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7Da37971bd9f9a80187b07b8cc0ba410d8; expires=Tue, 27-Aug-2013 11:36:02 GMT; path=/
Content-type: text/html

Comment: No error messages? Can you post the code?

Comment: @Jeemusu what is the above one ?

Comment: The one above isn't an error message as such, but it seems that your HTML header being spat out.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing only controller name in cronjob but you should write method name also when the method is index. So in your case you write `birthday/index` in your cronjob.
OR

1. Create `cron.php` config file in `application/config` with data as:

> $config['CRON_TIME_LIMIT']=0;
>
> $config['argv']   =array(1 => 'birthday');
>
> $config['CRON_BETA_MODE']=false;

2. Create cron.php at root parrallel to application folder containing data as

> //!/usr/bin/php

```
<?php
define('CRON', TRUE);

// Load CRON config
require('/home/dlp/public_html/abc.org/application/config/cron.php');
// Set CRON mode ( live or beta )
define('CRON_BETA_MODE', $config['CRON_BETA_MODE']);

// Set index.php location
if (isset($config['CRON_CI_INDEX']) && $config['CRON_CI_INDEX'])
    define('CRON_CI_INDEX', $config['CRON_CI_INDEX']);
else
    define('CRON_CI_INDEX', '/home/dlp/public_html/abc.org/index.php');

if (count($argv) < 2)
    if (count($config['argv'])) {
        $argv = array_merge($argv, $config['argv']);
        $_SERVER['argv'] = $argv;
    } else
        die('Use: php cron.php controller/method');

// Simulate an HTTP request
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $argv[1];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $argv[1];
//$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']   = $config['SERVER_NAME'];
// Set run time limit
set_time_limit($config['CRON_TIME_LIMIT']);

// Run CI and capture the output
ob_start();

chdir(dirname(CRON_CI_INDEX));
//  echo "== ".CRON_CI_INDEX; die;
require( CRON_CI_INDEX );           // main CI index.php file
$output = ob_get_contents();

if (CRON_FLUSH_BUFFERS === TRUE)
    while (@ob_end_flush());          // display buffer contents
        else
    ob_end_clean();

echo "\n";
?>
```

3. Run cron the file as php

> /home/dlp/public_html/abc.org/cron.php

Comment: Hi, I followed steps above I am getting "CLI script access allowed only"