# cron job not works for codeigniter 2.2.5

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

I have used following command in cpanel to run cron but its not working.
PHP version : 5.4

Codeigniter Version : 2.2.5

Please help me!!

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/subdomain/index.php controller function
```

Comment: What is "not working"? Any error messages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460678/cli-command-line-interface-cron-job-not-getting-correct-controller

Comment: i have checked error log there is no error, i have to send email and sms through cron , actually if i hit url directly then it has worked.... is there any method  to see error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command

```
 wget -O - -q -t 1 http://domain.com/subdomain/index.php/controller/function
```